# process.nextTick(function() { throw err; }) rror: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND noder noder:27017 - nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodes

When I first time hit the http://localhost:8080, it gives me correct response, but shows below error too. When again hit http://localhost:8080, I see nothing on UI.

```
D:\node_workspace\node-token-jwt\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND noder noder:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

I am using node.js. How can I fixed this ?

**server.js**

```
// get the packages 
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var User   = require('./app/models/user'); // get our mongoose model


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

**user.js**

```
// get an instance of mongoose and mongoose.Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ 
    name: String, 
    password: String, 
    admin: Boolean 
}));
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    'secret': 'ilovescotchyscotch',
    'database': 'mongodb://noder:noderauth&54;proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/test'
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-token-jwt",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.7",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the whole error message? The stack trace would help know where the error come from.

Comment: Yez, that's the full stack trace !!

Comment: 27017 is the standard mongoDB port, are you sure you should connect to it with a socket? And that mongoDB is started and listening? Does it work if you put the mongoDB in localhost?

Comment: Hey me too getting the same error. Here is my error if you are able to solve it. then please look in to my error too.

My db is online.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Mongodb isn't running

try

typing "mongod" then restart the server